# How can I get the value (object) of a Resource's property?

Tags: java, rdf, kotlin, jena, apache-jena

I have the following code, in which I find a resource by its e-mail.

```
val varn = "x"
val query = createQuery("""SELECT ?${varn}
                    WHERE { ?x  <http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#EMAIL>  "${email}" }""")
val qexec = createQueryExecution(ds, query)
val rs = qexec.execSelect()
if (rs.hasNext()) {
    val solution = rs.nextSolution()
    val rec = solution[varn]
    // Here I need to find the value of the property FirstContactTime
}
```

Now I want to find out whether `rec` has a property `FirstContactTime` and if yes, its value.

I tried `rec.model.listObjectsOfProperty(ds.defaultModel.createProperty(FirstContactTime))` but it doesn't return anything. The debugger says `rec` does have a property `FirstContactTime`.

[image: Debugger]

How can I get the value of `FirstContactTime` (`2017-03-03T10:35:00Z`) in my code?

Comment: Screenshots are very difficult to work with. Please replace the screenshot with the text. The highlight isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the property in the data is `FirstContactDateTime` not `FirstContactTime`.

The SPARQL you're looking for is something like this --

```
PREFIX  vcard:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#>
PREFIX     ex:  <http://example.com/schema/person/>

SELECT ?user ?email ?firstcontact
 WHERE
   {               ?x  vcard:EMAIL              ?email         .
      OPTIONAL  {  ?x  ex:firstContactDateTime  ?firstcontact  }
   }
```